# GridView PageIndexChanging event is not firing inside UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have not found any solution of my problem:

> GridView paging event `gvBanquet_PageIndexChanging` not firing when it is inside an UpdatePanel.

As problem code is here:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>

  <div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
  <asp:GridView ID="gvBanquet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
      OnRowCommand="gvBanquet_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
      EmptyDataText="No record found!" OnPageIndexChanging="gvBanquet_PageIndexChanging" 
      ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
      <Columns>

      // here are templates 

      </Columns>
      <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
  </asp:GridView>

  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->

  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvBanquet" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is a paging event:

```
protected void gvBanquet_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvBanquet.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

   // fill and bind gridview here
}
```

I have added a break point but its not firing.

[image]

How I can fire paging buttons?

[image]

Comment: show your `getdata` code

Comment: @Webruster I have edited my question.

Comment: `DLBqt.SelectBanquet` code ?

Comment: that's a simple method that runs `select` statement to get records from database and returns DataTable.

Comment: @Webruster I've edited question.

Comment: @asifali  join discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156323/discussion

Comment: worst question !!! with pagination need to fetch data with pagecount and page this not even handled.  check with this site https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16238/GridView-Custom-Paging

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni can you explain this *with pagination need to fetch data with pagecount and page this not even handled* and my question is paging event not firing.

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni , go easy on OP , there is no worst question , things that are known to u and doesn't known to OP it doesn't make it as worst

Comment: @Asif.Ali check my update

Answer (score 4):

There is no binding method of the `GridView` so I offer two methods (both works)
**Method 1**: Declarative binding with `SqlDataSource`:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%--ScriptManager required by UpdatePanel --%>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm" />
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="sqlNWind">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <%--Triggers are redundant because GridView is inside the UpdatePanel --%>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlNWind" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindCnn %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName, Products.CategoryID, Categories.CategoryName FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
```

No Code Behind required.

**Method 2**: Binding from Code Behind:

```
.aspx
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm" />
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="gvProducts_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" DataKeyNames="ProductID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>

.aspx.vb

Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        BindProds()''//Bind initial
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub gvProducts_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    gvProducts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    BindProds()''//Bind when pageIndex changing
End Sub

Private Sub BindProds()
    Using cnn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NorthwindCnn").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName, Products.CategoryID, Categories.CategoryName FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID", cnn)
            Dim da As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New Data.DataTable()
            da.Fill(dt)
            da.Dispose()
            gvProducts.DataSource = dt
            gvProducts.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The code is `VB.NET`. I hope OP can translate it to `C#`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible case without seeing your `getdata` code is that :

you should read the data set (your case Datatable ) which was used to load the gridview, each time your page index is changed. By this way, you could ensure that in each seperate postback which has been triggered by the gridview page number, results will be populated.

**Update**

Try to add a trigger

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvBanquet" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
 </Triggers>
```

Comment: @Asif.Ali please update your question , after update

Comment: `asp:GridView` doesn't have `AutoPostBack` property.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev thanks , modified my answer, i overlooked it